# Matrix date field error - 'Undefined index' at line 735 in file libraries/Localize.php for ADMIN panel

Tags: php, expressionengine

After adding date field to matrix field type getting following error in ADMIN panel:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: Europe/London
Filename: libraries/Localize.php
Line Number: 735
```

Comment: You need to post the code you are trying to get helped

Comment: i am using matrix plugin in admin panel and got this error on entry edit page. seems its related to timezone issue.

Comment: Please add Matrix version and EE version to your question.  In your control panel what is the value of Admin > Localization Settings > Site Timezone?  I don't see "Europe" as a choice in EE 2.8.1.  Perhaps you want "United Kingdom" + "London"?

Answer (score 0):

In your control panel what is the value of Admin > Localization Settings > Site Timezone?

I don't see "Europe" as a choice in EE 2.8.1 and expect this is the cause of your problem.

Trying changing to "United Kingdom" + "London"